# Different shaders on different textures in the same spritebatch

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, shader

My question is simple: How can I apply different shaders to different textures in the same spritebatch?

I cannot do multiple spritebatches due to image depths.

I am designing my game engine in 2D.

Comment: So can you not use `spritebatch.begin(parameters1); ... spritebatch.end(); spritebatch.Begin(parameters1); ... ` ?

Comment: I could, but it would mess up the way I layer images (that is with float depth).

Comment: I think I'll be facing similar issue very soon. I'm afraid there's no other option than to change your code to be able to work with seperate SpriteBatch.Begin/End sequences :/

Comment: Aah, ok. Well that sucks. =(

Comment: you could render all textures to one and then apply shader... i give up on this fload depth, and i render textures manually. first in, first draw.

Comment: Sorry, that wouldn't be smart of me to switch back to code-based depth.  And I'm not going to give up the illusion of depth for some effects.

Comment: It's more efficient to batch stuff `per shader` across everything in the scene than to context switch all the time for each model

Comment: @MickyDuncan, yea, I still planned to do that. I just wasn't sure if it was possible to do it in the way I said above. Thank you